# Embed Chatango in my Cargo built website using HTML

Tags: html, embed

Hello Chatango is giving me the following code to embed into my site:

```
<script id="cid0020000283122845468" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 350px;height: 500px;">
    {
        "handle": "sweettapes",
        "arch": "js",
        "styles": {
            "a": "feff00",
            "b": 100,
            "c": "000000",
            "d": "000000",
            "k": "feff00",
            "l": "feff00",
            "m": "feff00",
            "p": "10",
            "q": "feff00",
            "r": 100,
            "fwtickm": 1
        }
    }
</script>
```

It loads and previews on my site builder (cargo) but when i save it and preview the page there's nothing to be seen.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm very inexperienced with custom coding so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question.

Best,
J

Comment: Sorry the code is this:<script id="cid0020000283122845468" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 350px;height: 500px;">{"handle":"sweettapes","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"feff00","b":100,"c":"000000","d":"000000","k":"feff00","l":"feff00","m":"feff00","p":"10","q":"feff00","r":100,"fwtickm":1}}</script>

Comment: you can insert into body tag, before </body>

Comment: maybe you can share too, your html code

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time.

I insert that into my HTML. There is no other HTML, just the above in the body. But nothing appears. The site link is here – https://sweet-tapes.com/chat

Any ideas?